# Using a Cursor to Create Triggers for all tables in a database

Tags: triggers, cursor

I am using SQL Server 2005

I am trying to create a trigger for each table contained within a database and keep getting an error which I do not understand and can not fix

If anyone has an idea of why I am getting this error or how I can resolve it that would be brilliant.

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @audit_action as varchar(100)

DECLARE RDS_cusor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [RawDataStorage].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 't_%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'tbl_%'

OPEN RDS_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM RDS_cursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.After_Insert_Trig
ON  [dbo].[t_Agent]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO RawDataStorage_Audit
(TableName,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
VALUES('TableName','audit_action',getdate());

END
GO

FETCH NEXT FROM RDS_cursor INTO @TableName

END   

CLOSE RDS_cursor   
DEALLOCATE RDS_cursor
```

This is the error I am getting:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@TableName".

any help would be greatly appreachiated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put this together, its a dynamic query that builds the sql to create the triggers using a cursor to grab the table names from the sysobjects.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RawDataStorage_Audit](
            ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            TableName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
            audDateLastChanged DATETIME null
  )          


Declare @TableName nvarchar(100)
Declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)

declare tables_cursor CURSOR FOR
            select [name] from sysobjects 
            where xtype = 'U' 
            and [name] not like 'sys%' 
            order by [name]
Open tables_cursor

fetch next from tables_cursor into @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin

--create trigger for insert on each table
            print @SQL
            set @SQL = 'create trigger trg_u_'+@TableName+'_Inserted '
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' on '+@TableName
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' for insert '
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' as '
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' begin '
            set @SQL = @SQL + '    insert into [dbo].[RawDataStorage_Audit] '
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' select ''' + @TableName +''', getdate()'
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' from inserted'
            set @SQL = @SQL + ' end'
            exec (@SQL)
            print @SQL

            fetch next from tables_cursor into @TableName
end

CLOSE tables_cursor
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor
```